# Optimistic locking & aggregate root's internal entity

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's assume I have the Aggregate root `Picture` with internal entity `Shape`. `Picture` contains list of shapes.

`Shape` will remain an internal entity of the `Picture` aggregate root because the `Picture` defines some rules among multiple `Shape` instances. Let's say you can't assign new `Shape` when `Picture` is read-only and `Picture` may not contain two `Shapes` of the same color. Having defined these rules, the aggregate root - knowing about all of its `Shapes` - can now consistently verify rules.

To not brake Law of Demeter, I am accessing the `Shape` always through the `Picture`.
My question is related to ptimistic locking with aggregate versioning. If I am updating color of the `Shape` through `Picture` root aggregate, am I increasing the version of the aggreagate root - `Picture` or only of the `Shape` ?

My assumption is - only of the `Shape`, because oposite would prevent parallel updating of multiple `Shapes` of one `Picture`.

But what if during update of the `Shape`, `Picture` was set to readonly mode?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: The answer pretty much lies in the question - *aggregate versioning* versions... Aggregates, not simple entities.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is related to ptimistic locking with aggregate versioning. If I am updating color of the Shape through Picture root aggregate, am I increasing the version of the aggreagate root - Picture or only of the Shape ?

You are increasing the version of the root.  Specifically, you are changing the aggregate root from one that "points to" `version:4` of Shape to one that points to `version:5`.

It's somewhat similar to how git handles file changes.  You edited the file, which means that the file name that used to point to blob:1 now points to blob:2.  But "file" is just a name in the tree, so we need to change the tree from one that says `{ file -> blob:1 }` to a tree that says `{ file -> blob:2 }`, and so on all the way up to the root.

Repeating the same idea another way, any fixed version of the aggregate is "immutable" -- I should be able to look at `version:4` all day, and not be affected by the changes that you are making to the Shape, which means your changes need to happen in a new version.

As a clarification: it's weird.

The aggregate is, as a data pattern, a single graph of relations that changes atomically, to ensure that the invariant is maintained.  But "objects" want to encapsulate their own state.  So we take something that is a single tree, and break it into pieces that are individually managed by an object, and then stitch them all back together again to create a single new tree.

Comment: Good explanation! I get the impression you're saying that the root will have a version property for each of its related entities. Just to be clear: there would be a single version property on the root (Picture)?

Answer (score 3):

Every time an Aggregate mutates it should increase the version number when using an optimistic locking mechanism. An Aggregate mutates when its Aggregate root or any of the nested Entities mutate. When a conflicts occurs, it means that a previous faster state mutation has already been committed and it cannot be rollback. It also mean that the later state mutation was based on old data and it must be re-executed.

However, this conflict should be transparently retried by the framework by re-executing the command (load, execute, persist). The Aggregate should not care about this situation, the domain logic should be the same. In other words, in case of conflict, the client should not even notice, the HTTP response (or whatever) should be the same, maybe a *little* slower.

Answer (score 1):

The version number relates to the aggregate as it's the aggregate whos state is changed when a shape changes colour. Not sure why this would prevent parallel updating as long as the updates don't actually conflict.

What I mean by that is let's say our AG is at version 3. It contains a red, yellow and blue triangle. Two commands are issued in parallel to change the red triangle to a green one and another command is issued to change blue one to a purple. Both commands are issued at version 3 so a concurrency error will be detected. But assuming you are using events, you can look back at the events and see that they don't conflict and can, therefore, allow the process to go through.

I have a blog post which goes into this in a lot more detail. You can find it here: [Handling Concurrency Conflicts in a CQRS and Event Sourced System](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/09/29/handling-concurrency-issues-cqrs-event-sourced-system/)

I hope that helps.

Comment: "Not sure why this would prevent parallel updating as long as the updates don't actually conflict." You can update it in parallel of course but you need a mechanism to take care of a concurrency conflict. At the end, you're writing to event store sequentially, as you are updating internal entity of the aggregate. The best in regards to concurrency would be to have Shape and Picture as the separate aggregate roots, BUT I will loose strong consistency between these entities...

Comment: Take a look at the article I linked - it deals with a way to handle the conflict.